# Uploaded Wordpress theme not finding pages and css

Tags: themes, database, uploads, remote

Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction. I am not finding any relevant info out there.

I have a finished WP site with a customized Bones Theme functioning perfectly locally. I have uploaded it many times and in many variations. The customized theme is recognized by its name and activated. The background-images from the image file show up but the issue is the entire content ie pages and css do not show.
I am using the MySQL data for wp-config which the provider has provided.
In the current attempt I have used the WP installation provided by the provider and have placed my theme in the themes folder using ftp.

I assuming it is not finding the wp_ database.

I'd like to post the code but am being told it looks like spam…

Comment: You can post some amount of code to make yourself clearer. It can be a database issue(most probable), static URL issue or server issue.

Answer (score 0):

"pages [...] do not show"

Page content is stored in the database, not as part of your theme.  It sounds like you've uploaded your theme to the hosted installation of WordPress, but you haven't yet copied your local database to the hosted installation.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of issues here. As [MadtownLems](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16666/madtownlems) mentioned, you may just need to copy your post and page content to the remote server. A simple export/import can do this: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/import-export-wordpress-website

Also, some themes store customizations as serialized data. What this means is, every time you store an option, it's saved in a big long string in the database that also stores the number of characters in that string. If you copy that serialized string to a different site, it's likely that your site URL has a different number of characters. For example if your local URL is localhost:8888/localinstall and your remote URL is http://example.com, your local domain has 27 characters and your remote domain has 18 characters, and all of your serialized data will no longer work. If you have copied the entire MySQL database, I would revert the remote server to a default installation of WordPress, export/import your content, then activate the theme and manually go through customizations - setting up menus, choosing background images, etc., etc.